# Largest eigenvalue of a subgraph of a graph.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, adjacency-matrix

> If $H$ is a subgraph of a graph $G$ then $\lambda_1(H) \leq \lambda_1(G)$, being $\lambda_1$ the largest eigenvalue of $H$ and $G$ respectively (which are defined as the eigenvalues of the adjancecy matrix of $H$ and $G$ respectively).

This is easy to prove if $G$ is connected and non-bipartite using [Perron-Frobenius Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perron%E2%80%93Frobenius_theorem), but I cannot prove it the other cases.

A similar question that I cannot solve is:

> Let $G$ be a connected graph. If $\lambda_1(H) = \lambda_1(G)$ then $H=G$ (In fact, is and if and only if).

Any idea on how to do it?

Comment: cauchy interlacing

Comment: @mathworker21 Which orthogonal projection is the proper one?

Comment: idk what you mean. see theorem 1 here. a principal submatrix corresponds to a subgraph. https://people.orie.cornell.edu/dpw/orie6334/Fall2016/lecture4.pdf

Comment: @mathworker21 And what if you just delete some edge? Then the matrix has the same dimension, so you cannot apply it.

Comment: ah yes, it only applies to induced subgraphs

Comment: @mathworker21 Any idea to the second part?

Comment: Is there anything you want to know not covered in my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173959/show-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-graph-is-strictly-larger-than-the-largest/317482)?

Comment: @MishaLavrov The second question is not cover at all and I also think your answer is not that correct because you are using the Perron-Frobenius theorem in some cases you cannot use it; for example when the graph is bipartite.

Comment: @Lecter The Perron-Frobenius theorem doesn't care if the graph is bipartite. If you have any nonnegative matrix, then it has a nonnegative eigenvector whose eigenvalue is greater than or equal to the others in absolute value. You need the matrix to be irreducible only if you care about uniqueness and strict inequalities.

Comment: (And I did cover the second question since it asks to show that when $H$ is a proper subgraph of a connected $G$, $\lambda_1(H) < \lambda_1(G)$; your question is the contrapositive of that.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov You cannot apply Perro-Frobenius directly to non-negative matrices. If they are not irreducible (which is the case for bipartite graphs) then you cannot appy and you cannot be sure that exists this nonnegative eigenvector or the spectral radius (which is the eigenvalue associated).

Comment: @MishaLavrov The proof is totally correct if they graph is connected and non-bipartite (because you can show that a connected graph has an irreducible adjancency matrix if and only if the graph is not bipartite). If the graph is non-connected I think you can do your proof aswell locally on the connected components, but what can you do if the graph is bipartite

Comment: @Lecter For nitpickers, I have changed the proof in the linked answer to avoid applying Perron-Frobenius. (Essentially, this is the proof of the easy cases of Perron-Frobenius, which is simple because we don't have to characterize irreducible matrices.)

Comment: @MishaLavrov Thanks. But I think my second question is on the air; because I'm asking how to prove that G=H when the largest eigenvalues of them are equal. But I think you can prove it if you have the same eigenvector for both largest eigenvalue, because then you can end up with A(G)=A(H).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the proof for [why $\lambda_1(H) \le \lambda_1(G)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3174824/383078), we can figure out what happens if $\lambda_1(H) = \lambda_1(G)$ by thinking through the implications when the inequalities are tight. (Note that the linked answer assumes $\lambda_n$ is the largest eigenvalue, but here I assume that $\lambda_1$ is the largest to be consistent with the question.)

Let $\mathbf w$ be a unit eigenvector of $A_H$ corresponding to $\lambda_1(H)$. We can assume that $w_i \ge 0$ for all $i$, because $\mathbf w$ is supposed to maximize the quadratic form associated to $A_H$, and replacing $w_i$ by $|w_i|$ can only increase that quadratic form. We also assume that $A_H$ and $A_G$ have the same size, by including isolated vertices in $H$ if necessary.

From the inequality chain
$$
\lambda_1(H) = \sup_{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : \|\mathbf x\|=1} \mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\!A_H\mathbf x = \mathbf w^{\mathsf T}\!A_H\mathbf w \le \mathbf w^{\mathsf T}\!A_G\mathbf w \le \sup_{\mathbf x \in \mathbb R^n : \|\mathbf x\|=1} \mathbf x^{\mathsf T}\!A_G\mathbf x = \lambda_1(G)
$$
we conclude that when $\lambda_1(H) = \lambda_1(G)$, we must have $\mathbf w^{\mathsf T}\!A_H\mathbf w = \mathbf w^{\mathsf T}\!A_G\mathbf w$ and also $\mathbf w^{\mathsf T}\!A_G\mathbf w = \lambda_1(G)$.

Focus on the second equation first; it will show that $\mathbf w$ is a $\lambda_1(G)$-eigenvector of $A_G$. To see this, write $\mathbf w$ in an orthonormal eigenvector basis $\mathbf v^{(1)}, \dots, \mathbf v^{(n)}$ of $A_G$ as $$\mathbf w = c_1 \mathbf v^{(1)} + \dots + c_n \mathbf v^{(n)}.$$ We assume $\|w\|=1$, so $c_1^2 + \dots + c_n^2 = 1$. Then $\mathbf w^{\mathsf T} \!A_G \mathbf w = \lambda_1(G) c_1^2 + \lambda_2(G) c_2^2 + \dots + \lambda_n(G) c_n^2$. This is a convex combination of the eigenvalues, and the only way it can be equal to $\lambda_1(G)$ is if $c_i = 0$ for all $i$ with $\lambda_i(G) < \lambda_1(G)$. But this means that $\mathbf w$ is a linear combination of the $\lambda_1(G)$-eigenvectors of $A_G$, so it is also such an eigenvector.

Now, return to the first equation. We have $$0 = \mathbf w^{\mathsf T}\!A_G\mathbf w - \mathbf w^{\mathsf T}\!A_H\mathbf w = \sum_{ij \in E(G)} 2w_iw_j - \sum_{ij \in E(H)} 2w_iw_j = \sum_{ij \in E(G) \setminus E(H)} 2w_iw_j.$$ By nonnegativity of $\mathbf w$, for every edge $ij$ that appears in $G$ but not in $H$, $w_iw_j=0$. In particular, **either $G=H$ and we are done**, or else some $w_i$ must be $0$.

Because $\mathbf w$ is an eigenvector, we know $A_G \mathbf w = \lambda_1(G)\mathbf w$. Then from $w_i = 0$ we conclude $$\sum_{j : ij \in E(G)} w_j = (A_G\mathbf w)_i = \lambda_1(G) w_i = 0.$$ Since all components of $\mathbf w$ are nonnegative, this means that $w_j=0$ for all $j$ such that $ij \in E(G)$: the zero components propagate to adjacent vertices.

This is true for *any* $i$ such that $w_i=0$: whenever $\mathbf w$ is zero at a vertex, it's zero at the vertex's neighbors. But then it's zero at those neighbors' neighbors, too, and so on... $G$ is connected, so by repeating this argument, we conclude that $\mathbf w = \mathbf 0$, which contradicts the assumption that $\mathbf w$ is an eigenvector of anything.

Comment: Awesome. The only thing I don't get is the part that you say: "G is connected, so by repeating this argument, we conclude that  w=0".

Comment: I've elaborated slightly. If $\mathbf w$ is zero at a vertex, it's zero at other vertices adjacent to it, but then you can apply the same argument to those vertices to conclude that it's zero at their neighbors, too. Eventually, you'll show that $\mathbf w$ is zero at every vertex, because you can get to every vertex from the starting one.

Answer (score 1):

For a not connected graph, note that the eigenvalues of the whole graph are just the union of the eigenvalues of the individual components so you can prove this componentwise.

I have no idea how this works for bipartite graphs.

Comment: And how would you do it? There is only missing the non induced subgraphs...

Answer (score 1):

Easy proofs:

**For the first question:**
let each have an n x n adjacency matrix, given by $A_G$ and $A_H$ respectively.

now consider, for $t\in [0,1]$
$F_G(t) = (1-t) \mathbf{11}^T + t\cdot A_G$
$F_H(t) = (1-t) \mathbf{11}^T + t\cdot A_H$

for t $\in [0,1)$
$\lambda_{max}\big(F_G(t)\big)\geq \lambda_{max}\big(F_H(t)\big)$
because $F_G(t) \geq F_H(t)$ (component wise) 
and all entries of the matrix are are positive so the result follows from Perron theory.

then 
for t $ = 1$
$\lambda_{max}\big(A_G\big) =\lambda_{max}\big(F_G(t)\big)\geq \lambda_{max}\big(F_H(t)\big) = \lambda_{max}\big(A_H\big)$
by (topological) continuity of eigenvalues.

**For the second question:**
We can assume WLOG that $A_H$ is a connected graph with the same n states as $A_G$.  If not, create $A_H^*$ that *is* connected --e.g. $A_H^* := \frac{1}{2}\big(A_H + A_G\big)$ --and $A_H\leq A_H^* \leq A_G$ with the right componentwise inequality strict in at least one place.  Re-running the first argument tells us $\lambda_{\max}(A_H) \leq  \lambda_{\max}(A_H^*)$.  The below argument would then proceed to show $\lambda_{\max}(A_H^*)\lt \lambda_{\max}(A_G)$. But again, for simplicity we proceed by assuming WLOG that that $A_H$ is a connected graph with the same n states as $A_G$.

from part 1 we know $\lambda_{max}\big(A_G\big) \geq \lambda_{max}\big(A_H\big)$
so divide out $\lambda_{max}\big(A_G\big)$ and we consider new graphs where $\lambda_{max}\big(A_G'\big)=1 \geq \lambda_{max}\big(A_H'\big)$

now effect similarity transform and consider
$P_G = D^{-1}A_G'D$
$P_H = D^{-1}A_H'D$
where $D=\text{Diag}(\mathbf v)$ and $\mathbf v$ is the Perron vector of $A_G$.

$P_G \mathbf 1 = \mathbf 1$  (i.e. this is a stochastic matrix)
and $P_H \mathbf 1 \leq \mathbf 1$ (componentwise) with equality iff $A_G = A_H$.  Otherwise $P_H$ is strictly substochastic in at least one row $i$ which means that state $i$ is transient, but since the graph is connected, and this is a communicating class property, *all* states in $A_H$ are transient so the matrix is not positive recurrent and there is no positive vector with eigenvalue one $\longrightarrow \lambda_{max}\big(A_H'\big) \lt 1$

an alternative finish is to consider
$S_n^{(H)} = \frac{1}{n}\big(P_H + P_H^2 + P_H^3 + ... + P_H^{n-1} + P_H^n\big)$
this matrix is strictly positive (by connected graph).  Since $P_H\mathbf 1 \leq \mathbf 1 \text{ suppose strict in some component} \longrightarrow S_n^{(H)}\mathbf 1 \leq \mathbf 1 \text{ strict in some component}$.
(Use associativity and non-negativity)

By Perron theory $\lambda_{max}\big(S_n^{(H)}\big)\lt 1$ which implies $\lambda_{max}\big(P_H\big) \lt 1= P_G$ and completes the proof.