# why there is no graph whose largest eigenvalue, $\lambda_1$, lies in the intervals $(0,1)$ or $(1,\sqrt{2})$?

Tags: graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

why there is no graph whose largest eigenvalue, $\lambda_1$, lies in the intervals $(0,1)$ or $(1,\sqrt{2})$? I think it's becaues of if  a graph doesn't have any edge then  $\lambda_1=0$, if it has one edge, then $\lambda_1=1$ and finally if it has two edges, then
$\lambda_1=\sqrt{2}$. For the graphs with more edges, $\lambda_1\geq \sqrt{2}$. Is it correct?
Thank you for the help.

Comment: I mean in one of them, not both of them. I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be more precise: a graph with two edges can still have largest eigenvalue $1$ if those two edges don't share any endpoints. What you mean is: a *connected* graph with two edges has largest eigenvalue $\sqrt 2$.

Except for that nitpick, you are correct, because [the largest eigenvalue of a graph is at least the largest eigenvalue of any subgraph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3173959/show-that-the-largest-eigenvalue-of-a-graph-is-strictly-larger-than-the-largest/3174824#3174824). Any graph either

- is empty, and all its eigenvalues are $0$, or
- has no components with more than one edge, and all its eigenvalues are $1$, $0$, or $-1$, or
- has a component with at least two edges, in which case that component contributes an eigenvalue of at least $\sqrt 2$, by the result above.

We could in theory continue this reasoning if we wanted to. No graph has a largest eigenvalue in the interval $(\sqrt 2, \frac{1+\sqrt5}{2})$, because $\sqrt2$ is the only possible eigenvalue of a connected graph with $2$ edges, and $\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$ is the smallest eigenvalue of a connected graph with $3$ edges.

Comment: Dear Misha, thank you for your answer.